Enum throws exception when fetching details
I want to generate an application from a JDL (jhipster 8.6.0).
This is a basic application with just an entity containing an enum value.
I'm also using Elasticsearch search engine.
The JDL is the above one :
application {
  config {
    applicationType monolith
    authenticationType oauth2
    baseName EnumTest
    buildTool maven
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    clientFramework angular
    clientTheme solar
    clientThemeVariant dark
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType postgresql
    enableHibernateCache true
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
    enableTranslation true
    languages [fr, en]
    messageBroker false
    microfrontends []
    nativeLanguage fr
    packageName fr.jhipster.test
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    reactive false
    searchEngine elasticsearch
    serviceDiscoveryType no
    skipUserManagement true
    testFrameworks [gatling, cucumber, cypress]
    websocket false
    withAdminUi true
  }

  entities *
}

entity Address {
  isoCountryCode IsoCountryCode
}

enum IsoCountryCode {
  FRA,
  ENG,
}

paginate * with pagination
dto * with mapstruct
service all with serviceImpl

Then, when I try to view one of the Address details, I got this exception
2024-07-22T09:29:35.569+02:00 ERROR 23384 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] f.m.l.d.web.rest.AddressResource         : Exception in getAddress() with cause = 'org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [fr.jhipster.test.domain.enumeration.IsoCountryCode]: 'fr.jhipster.test.domain.Address.isoCountryCode' (setter)' and exception = 'Could not set value of type [fr.jhipster.test.domain.enumeration.IsoCountryCode]: 'fr.jhipster.test.domain.Address.isoCountryCode' (setter)' 

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [fr.jhipster.test.domain.enumeration.IsoCountryCode]: 'fr.jhipster.test.domain.Address.isoCountryCode' (setter)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
(...)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [fr.jhipster.test.domain.enumeration.IsoCountryCode]: 'fr.jhipster.test.domain.Address.isoCountryCode' (setter)
        at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:88)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set fr.jhipster.test.domain.enumeration.IsoCountryCode field fr.jhipster.test.domain.Address.isoCountryCode to fr.jhipster.test.domain.enumeration.IsoCountryCode
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799)
        at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:57)

It seems to be a type mismatch, what did I do wrong with my JDL?
